# PostgresSQL сортировка (взгляд с админской части)

Tags: postgresql, dba

Есть postgresql 15-ой версии.
Имеется таблица на 243млн записей.
При попытке вылнить следующий запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  visits_hits 
WHERE 
  url like '%tinkoff.fstravel.com/%' 
order by
  date desc
limit 10;
```

Запрос задумывается на крайне долгое время и на сервере потихоньку начинает съедаться оперативная память. Как только оперативка подходит к концу и съедается своп, срабатывает oom-killer и прибивает постгрес.

Вопрос: каким образом можно заставить постгрю производить сортировку на диске а не в оперативной памяти?

Характеристики:
машина Linux ubuntu 22.04
16 ядер
оперативки 31гб
диск 1Тб ssd, занят на 287гб
Postgres - 15
shared_buffers = 3900MB
work_mem 50MB

скриншот таблицы по дкапотом
[image: tbl]

Прекрасно понимаю что такую таблицу нужно декомпозировать, но пока такой возможности нет и хотелось бы для начала сделать так что бы пользовательские запросы не заваливали базу

Скриншот плана запроса без сортировки

[image: План запроса без сортировки]

Comment: а чего вы к сортировке сразу перешли, там еще выбрать надо все данные прочитав всю таблицу целиком сначала с таким-то запросом

Comment: без сортировки запрос отрабатывает. правда за 10 минут. На тестовой машине подобный запрос отрабатывает моментально, но там стоит 14-й постгрес

Comment: Если вдруг каким то магическим образом, у вас на поле url есть индекс, то ищите не `like %google.com%` а `url like 'http://google.com%' OR url like 'https://google.com%'`. А в целом, разбирайте URL на домен и все остальное. домены в отдельный справочник с индексом на имени (можно еще реверсивно записать, если по поддоменам искать надо), domain_id в таблицу. На него индекс + дата

Comment: На тестовой машине где моментально поди и данных на пару порядков меньше.

Comment: На тестовой машине 187млн записей =)

Comment: еще значит в чем то различие. Запрос может не совсем такой, индексы может какие-то использует. 200млн записей никакой сервер быстро не прочитает. Разве что оно целиком у него в буфере лежит. Посмотреть можно план выполнения и сравнить в чем разница.

Comment: К сожалению даже план выполнения построить невозможно. Съедает оперативку при попытке его сделать. Индексов по полю url нет. GIN индекс создать так же не дает из-за типа данных.

Comment: план выполнения строится до выполнения запроса. Невозможно в вашем случае будет посмотреть `explain analyze`, который показывает фактический план после выполнения запроса, а простой `explain` просто строит план и не трогает данные.

Comment: Любопытно, есть ли индекс по ``date`` (лучше desc) на тестовой и прод.машине? Если падает на этапе сортировки - может быть важно. Можете попробовать заменить ``select *`` на ``select id,url,date`` и замерить?

Comment: покажите pg_log_backend_memory_contexts от запущенного запроса ( https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-14-memory-dumps/ ). Что-то идёт сильно не так, запрос и таблица нормальные если нет задачи их ускорять, нормально если будет делать много временных файлов, ненормально если жрёт память. 15.5 минорное обновление стоит? не помню чего-то релевантного для такого запроса, но могло быть.

Comment: Благодарю за советы. В теле вопроса добавил скриншот с планом запроса, но план запроса без сортировки. Сейчас грешу на компрессию и дал задание разработчикам убрать её. На момент написания комментария версия постгреса 15.4

Comment: так это ещё и не постгресовая табличка даже. А что это? timescaledb так вроде выглядит. Что же без сомнений важные детали не указываете?